# UML diagrams of WordPress

Tags: oop

Where can I find UML diagrams of WordPress (Data flow diagrams, State diagram, component diagram, use case diagram, deployment diagram)?

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know any sequence diagram for WordPress but if you decide to built them yourself (which would be appreciated :-) ) you may get some inspiration from these [sequence diagrams created for Drupal](http://modeling-languages.com/better-understanding-drupal-module-interactions-thanks-to-uml/)

Comment: From the linked article: "*You already know that I dropped Drupal to move to WordPress[...]*" ;o) . . . . . . . I think the diagrams you refer to are not there anymore, which is why it is recommended to embed/quote than to link.

Answer (score 0):

You can found Wordpress DB visual overview here,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: It just gives ER Diagram